# processing speed difference between CSS class and id

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

For this question, I'm only comparing a browser's speed in rendering the CSS on 2 elements which are different only in that one has a class and one has an id.

(This has nothing to do with JS identification, anchor use, etc.)

```
<div class="myclass">classed element</div>
<div id="myid">ided element</div>
```

Does anyone have *numbers* on this? I have read that CSS ids are 'faster,' but by how much? I'm going to hazard a guess that it's negligible, but it would be interesting to know.

Comment: You mean the actual rendering of the element or querying for the element in the DOM?

Comment: I did use the word rendering in the question, but I guess I'm really thinking about _querying_ the DOM in order to render.

Comment: I know you are asking about rendering speed. That said there are other considerations. Keep in mind, of course, there are semantic reasons to use ID instead of class. I'm not sure that matters for screen readers and accessibility.  Of course if using JavaScript to query page, IDs will be faster, but on most pages of reasonable size it's probably negligible.

I increasingly see over-use of classes in markup/CSS, and I'm not sure why, when in cases where there is a unique element an ID will do.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

https://web.archive.org/web/20190901050026/http://oli.jp/2011/ids/

ID's *are* faster in some cases, but not all

> It’s a common belief that ID selectors are the fastest, but this comes with a big caveat: IDs are fastest CSS selector only if they’re the key selector. What’s that? Well, while you probably read selectors from left to right, browsers read them from right to left.

There's also a performance test here for your numbers request: https://web.archive.org/web/20190901050026/http://oli.jp/2011/ids/#table1

**Conclusion**

ID's used correctly are faster, but with such a minimal difference vs classes - it's not worth any consideration.

> It seems to me that there are no convincing reasons to use IDs in selectors for CSS styling¹, as CSS classes can do everything IDs can. Hopefully you’ll agree there are some good reasons not to. Think about it the next time you start a personal project or redesign your own site, and try adding a class (or ARIA landmark roles) for styling instead. Save IDs for fragment identifiers or JavaScript hooks

Comment: Website is down :C
WebArchive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20190901050026/http://oli.jp/2011/ids/