# When using .map and input tag inside the index is always 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of documents and I need to upload each one so I am mapping the documents list and then I use `<input />` to select a file from computer and then upload it but somehow the input tag will switch the `item` index to 0 and I am not uploading the corect file.

Here is the code I am using

```
{documents.map((item, index) => {
            console.log(item, index) // {_id: "5f10385d002908065b76f885", name: "Baccalaureate Diploma", __typename: "Document"}, 5
            return (
              <div key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                  <Checkbox
                    checked={documents.some(document => document.name === item.name && document.approved)}
                    disabled={true}
                  />
                  <div style={{ paddingTop: 5 }}>
                    <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{ display: "flex" }}
                  onClick={() => console.log(item)}
                  // {_id: "5f10385d002908065b76f885", name: "Baccalaureate Diploma", __typename: "Document"}, 5
                >
                  <input
                    id="file"
                    type="file"
                    name="document"
                    style={{ display: "none" }}
                    accept="/*"
                    onChange={(e) => console.log(item, index)}
                    // {_id: "5f10385d002908065b76f880", name: "2 Passport Pictures", __typename: "Document"}, 0
                  />
                  <label for="file" className="btn-3"><CloudUploadIcon />  <span style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>{loading ? "Uploading" : "Upload"}</span></label>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
```

So as you can see I have couple of console logs which up `input` tag it will show me the exact document I need to upload. But then it is switched to very first one index `0`

Any idea how can I fix this and maybe an explanation?

Comment: May be same id and same name?

Comment: @bravemaster what do you mean? Look for the comments which are the responses from `console.log` and the id and name is different none of the object are same

Comment: I think all the inputs have same id, so onChange function is bound to only first input element. I can't think of any reason other than that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50923784/should-ids-be-unique-in-the-react-dom

Comment: @bravemaster it was because all had `id="file"` so I made it `id={`file`${index}}` now its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because all inputs have the same id attribute, so onChange function was binded to first input element only.

Try to assign different id to each input element, instead of

```js
<input id="file" />
```

you can do like this:

```js
<input id={`file_${index}`} />
```